# Determining if a test-kitchen test passed or failed

Tags: testing, automated-tests, chef-infra, test-kitchen

We have a script that looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for cookbook in $cookbooks; do
    cd /path/to/$cookbook
    kitchen test;
    # Log whether the test failed or passed
done;

# Print number of tests passed and number of tests failed
```

How can I determine if my `kitchen test` passed or failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check exit status of `kitchen test` command, and increment counter like:

```
#!/bin/bash
let failed=0
let passed=0

for cookbook in $cookbooks; do
  cd /path/to/$cookbook
  kitchen test;

  if [ $? -ne 0 ]
  then
     failed=$((failed + 1))
  else
    passed=$((passed + 1))
  fi
done;

echo "There was $passed passed and $failed failed tests."
```